# PHP query in mysql and keep in selected

Tags: php, html

I want to mysql query and keep in select dropdown list

```
<select name="selectjob"></select>
```

and this is mysql query

```
SELECT repair_id FROM `repair_list` where status = 'work'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more clear and specific?

Comment: Your question is unclear at all

Comment: OK i want to create dropdownlist , my value in dropdown list come form 
mysql query ex: SELECT repair_id FROM `repair_list` where status = 'work'

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*`, its deprecated now. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
    //db connection
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
    mysql_select_db("database");

    //query
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT repair_id FROM repair_list where status = 'work'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    $select= '<select name="selectjob">';
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
          $select.='<option value="'.$rs['repair_id'].'">'.$rs['repair_id'].'</option>';
      }
    }
    $select.='</select>';
    echo $select;
```

OR using mysqli as my genius friend in the comment suggested:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT repair_id FROM repair_list where status = 'work'");

    echo "<select name='selectjob'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['repair_id'].'">'.$row['repair_id'].'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: my friend start living in today's world. `mysql_*` is deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: is ok but value is not in my select dropdownlist

Comment: @NonBrazilian, this is a head start. Try debugging further buddy!

Answer (score 2):

This will guide you through:

```
$status = 'work';

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT repair_id FROM `repair_list` where status = ?");

$query->bind_param("s",$status);

if (!$query->execute())
{
    $flag = false;
}

$query->bind_result($repair_id);

$select= '<select name="selectjob">';
while($query->fetch()){
      $select.='<option value="'.$repair_id.'">'.$repair_id.'</option>';
  }
}
$select.='</select>';
```

Comment: plus 1 for prepared statement. You should use prepared statements always!

Answer (score 0):

`select.php`

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT repair_id FROM repair_list where status ='work'");
$selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $repair_id[] = array('repair_id' => $selected_row['repair_id ']);
        }
        echo json_encode($repair_id, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

`JS`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'select.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var select = ('#select');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(select).append('<option id=' + data[i].repair_id + ' value="' + data[i].repair_id + '">' + data[i].repair_id + '</option>');

            }
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
});
```

`html`

```
<select name="selectjob" id="select"></select>
```

Try using ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT repair_id FROM repair_list where status = 'work'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0):
    $html ='';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html.='<option value="'.$row['repair_id'].'">'.$row['repair_id'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $html;
else:
    echo "0 results";
endif;
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear that where you have saved the selected repair_id. By changing value of $selectedValue variable you can show desired selected value.

```
<select name="selectjob"></select>

    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT repair_id FROM `repair_list` where status = 'work'");
    $selectedValue = 2; //some id which is selected
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['repair_id']?>" <?php echo ($row['repair_id'] == $selectedValue)? ' selected="selected"': ''?>><?php echo $row['repair_id'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
```